# Drawing a graph of data having not uniform independent variables

Tags: excel-formula

Excel is capable of drawing a graph when the independent variable data is uniformly spaced:

> 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ...

Is there a method to draw a graph when this is not true?

> 0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.8 ...

With a naive approach Excel puts these values at equal spaces on the graph.

Comment: Try a scatter plot

Comment: If you take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881370/excel-scatter-plot-incorrect-due-to-wrong-format-values/46881741) you will see Excel will treat scatter plots with non numeric data for the X-axis as a line plot insteas